# Changing the background image of a button on Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am currently trying to use two buttons, button A and button B. They are on separate activities, and when button B is pressed, the background image on button A should change. So far, here is my relevant code

activity_main.xml

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button_a"
        android:layout_width="295dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:background="@drawable/before_press" />
```

activity_2.xml

```
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_b"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/Button B"
        />
```

activity_2.kt

```
 button_b.setOnClickListener {
           button_a.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.after_press)
            val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
```

I believe it may be something to do with the android:background= being in @drawable form and not R.drawable form, but not sure

I tried many different options and searched this website also

any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Remove `startActivity` and test. Most probably the background is changing but you are not able to see it because right after that you are switching your activity.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line `button_a.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.after_press)` on button_b click and paste in `onCreateView()` of `MainActivity` and pass a boolean with intent like `intent.putBooleanExtra("isPressed",true);` and in `MainActivity` on `onCreateView()` check `intent.getBooleanExtra("isPressed")` is true then change the background color of button_a like `button_a.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.after_press)`;

you can not access button_a inside `Activity2` class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change Button to ImageButton

like this:

```
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button_a"
        android:layout_width="295dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:background="@drawable/before_press" />
```